# windbg: How to determine the opcode for an assembly language instruction or set of instructions

Tags: windbg

I am working on an assignment to perform an exploit using a rop chain.
While I understand the basics behind rop, I don't know how to convert instructions like

```
xchg eax, esp; retn;
```

to their opcodes.

I tried using:

```
0:005> a
input> xchg eax,esp
```

but the address given just points to a totally different kind of instruction in my program.
I believe it was an add command.

Comment: @yyVob, thanks this really helped clear up the use of windbg to find the opcodes I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[RTA](http://www.woodmann.com/collaborative/tools/index.php/RTA) is an easy to use tool that allows you to enter either opcodes or mnemonics and will convert them from one to the other.

In the example below, I entered `XCHG EAX,ESP` and `RETN` on the right, and RTA produced `94` and `C3` on the left:

[image: RTA]

If, on the other hand, you really want to use WinDbg, then you need to do the following:

1. Load a target into WinDbg
2. Type <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter Input mode
3. Type your mnemonics (for example, `xchg eax,esp`), <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again to escape Input mode
5. Type <kbd>u</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> to show the disassembly of what you just assembled

​See below for an example:

```
0:000> a
778e05a6 xchg eax,esp
xchg eax,esp
778e05a7 

0:000> u
ntdll!LdrVerifyImageMatchesChecksum+0x633:
778e05a6 94              xchg    eax,esp
```

Comment: Please note that using the `a` command with no parameters will start overwriting bytes at the instruction pointer. To create scratch space specifically for assembling instructions, use `.dvalloc`, then call `a` with the address of the allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use assembler. 
Or online assembler such as [this](https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm)
Or you can use Ida's Edit-->Patch program-->Assemble submenu if you use Ida.